# Pass int into function, return NSString

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm very new to Objective-c and trying to understand blocks a little better. As a task for myself, I'm trying to write fizz-buzz in a variety of methods.

I'm currently working with blocks, but I've run into a syntax problem I don't get yet.

In the following non-working function, I want to pass in an int and return a type of NSString.

```
NSString (^whichMessage)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return @"Test";
};
```

However I get an error stating:

```
Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'NSString (^_strong)(int)' with an expression of type 'NSString *(^)(int)'
```

Can anyone explain what the problem with my sample code is, and also what the proper form is?

I am following the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

(For the sake of clarity, here is the sample code on the linked page)

```
int multiplier = 7;
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return num * multiplier;
};
```

Going by the graphic at the top of the page, I thought that by changing the block type to NSString and the return type to also be a NSString, it would work. But alas, it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite simple. Your block returns a pointer to a string not an actual string. We always work with pointers to objects not the actual objects themselves

```
         |
         v
NSString *(^whichMessage)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return @"Test";
};
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that. Can you also explain why the pointer declaration is required when using NSString, but not when the return type is an int like in the original example on the Apple docs page?

Comment: An int is a scalar type which are commonly used with stack based storage (doesn't have to be). Objects (in Objective-C) are always created on the heap and then you are passed a reference to that object.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a *:

```
NSString* (^whichMessage)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return @"Test";
};
```

Objective-C only uses heap-based objects referenced by pointer. You cannot declare a stack-based Objective-C object like in C++.

The notable exception to that rule is blocks, which act as Objective-C objects and can be stack-based.

Answer (score 1):

You forget a star `*`:

```
NSString* (^whichMessage)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return @"Test";
};
```